# Search on a abstract base class in Django vs concrete (multi-table) inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-models

I currently have an abstract base class that several of my models inherit from. I have run into an issue trying to filter on it.

I was told in Django you can NOT filter on an `abstract` model and Django ORM can only search tables. So the alternative I have found is `concrete (multi-table) inheritance`. But after reading [a post on how this creates bad performance in Django](http://jacobian.org/writing/concrete-inheritance/) I'm hoping there is another alternative?

Is it possible to search on a abstract base class in Django i.e. filter? I'm using Django 1.6.1 there has to be an option other than filtering on every table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad performance is rather relative imo. Do you expect high db concurrency? There's nothing wrong with leaf inheritance if it solves your problem. Afaik Jacob is just making people aware what's going on beneath the hood in his article.

Heads up: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1034/